# Eclipse Mars + Fedora 20 + KDE = black-on-black tooltips

Tags: fedora, colors, theme, eclipse, dialog

So, I'm using a system with Fedora 20 installed, running a KDE 4.14.7 desktop. (I don't have root access so please no complaints about why I don't just upgrade my distro.)

I have just installed Eclipse Mars.1 (in my home directory), and it runs fine, but - the tooltips I get (e.g. hover line error descriptions) appear as black-on-black (!)

I've seen some similar complaints online, from several years ago, about this problem on Ubuntu systems, but that's not me... also, note that I'm not root, so I can't change any KDE or GTK system-wide defaults, only personal settings.

What can I do?

**Notes:**

- I've seen [suggestion](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1069038/)s to use "gnome-color-chooser" and fiddle with its settings, but I don't have that.
- I've tried changing the KDE tooltip background, no effect.
- I've tried the Eclipse Color Theme add-on, and with some themes the background is dark gray, or the foreground color is dark gray; but I still can't edit just that (and dark gray on black is not good enough either).
- None of [these suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45001/how-to-fix-black-tooltips-in-eclipse) have worked either.

Comment: Fedora 20 is out of maintenance, upgrade.

Comment: @vonbrand: As I said above, I'm just a user on that machine, I can't upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me with Eclipse Mars and Fedora 24.

You need to run Eclipse using GTK 2, and change the tooltip colours in your chosen GTK theme.  My theme is Zukitre/ so I edited the gtkrc file here:

```
sudo vi '/usr/share/themes/Zukitre/gtk-2.0/gtkrc'
```

Find the line that sets tooltip_bg_color and tooltip_fg_color and change it as follows:

```
gtk-color-scheme   = "tooltip_bg_color:#f5f5c5\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000" # Tooltips.
```

Then run eclipse using GTK2 by setting the following environment variable:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

Comment: Under 1 year is old to you... :-(  anyway, thank you for the effort, but the thing is that I don't have root access at all. Can you adapt your answer with user-specific files & paths to change?

Comment: @einpoklum: have you tried just `export SWT_GTK3=0; eclipse`? that fixed it for me under ubuntu without touching anything.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question relating to KDE 4, but I thought I'd just chime in with how I solved this in KDE Plasma 5 (Kubuntu):

1. Open System Settings.
2. Click on **Colors** (in the *Appearance* section).
3. Un-tick Apply Colors to non-Qt Applications.
4. Click on the **Apply** button.

[image: Correct Tool-tip Colors for GTK Apps in KDE]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can no longer check since all of my versions have changed...